# Problem with Zend and addRoute()

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route

With this code:

```
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance(); 
$router = $frontController->getRouter();
$router->addRoute(
    'test',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        '/test/:action/:type/:id',
        array(
            'controller' => 'admin'
        )
    )
);
```

http://app/test/param1/param2/param3 -> OK

http://app/test/param1/param2/ -> FAIL

In the second case the application don't recognize param2.

It seems that the application needs the param3 in order to read the param2...

How can I do it?

Thanks!

---

Test with the code from @RageZ

```
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance(); 
$router = $frontController->getRouter();
$router->addRoute(
    'test',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        '/test/:action/:type/:id',
        array(
            'controller' => 'admin',
            'id' => 0
        ),
        array(
            'id' => '\d+'
        )
    )
);
```

http://app/test/ -> OK

http://app/test/some -> OK

http://app/test/some/more -> FAIL

http://app/test/some/more/andmore -> OK

Ideas?

Comment: last code is missing default for type... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try giving a default value to everything

```
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance(); 
$router = $frontController->getRouter();
$router->addRoute(
    'test',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        '/test/:action/:type/:id',
        array(
            'controller' => 'admin',
            'action' => 'index',
            'type' => 'sometype',
            'id' => 0
        ),
        array(
            'id' => '\d+'
        )
    )
);
```

Just tried your code in some test project and this fixed it hope it works for you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide a default value if the parameter is optional.

```
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance(); 
$router = $frontController->getRouter();
$router->addRoute(
    'test',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        '/test/:action/:type/:id',
        array(
            'controller' => 'admin',
            'id' => 0
        ),
        array(
            'id' => '\d+'
        )
    )
);
```

Nothing to do with your question but it's a good practice to use the third param of addRoute. Zend Framework would verify that the parameters value match the format you have specified, in that case I suppose id is an integer.

Comment: @joanballester: up to you to know if you need to have a default value and specify the format. in your case tboth url would work

Comment: I'm sorry, but... I can't! I will continue trying (I've edited the post)

Comment: @joanballester: let me setup a dummy application to test